# Audio JavaScript autoplay pause button does not work

Tags: javascript, audio, autoplay, audio-player

I really like simplicity of audio, JavaScript plugin and it fit my needs very well, only one problem is that when set to autoplay Pause button do not work. This happens in Chrome and FF. It works fine in IE. Please check official example:

http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test3.html

If you try to pause autoplayed example it will not work. Tried to do may things even to contact developer who did the script so far no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test 3 - audio.js</title>
    <style>
      p { clear: both; }
    </style>
    <script src="../audiojs/audio.js"></script>
    <script>
      audiojs.events.ready(function() {
        audiojs.createAll();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>audiojs.create(element, settings)</h1>
    <p>preload="none"</p>
    <audio src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/juicy.mp3" preload="none"></audio>
    <p>autoplay="autoplay"</p>
    <audio src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/juicy.mp3" autoplay></audio>
    <p>loop="loop"</p>
    <audio src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/juicy.mp3" loop></audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What have you tried code-wise?

Comment: Tried simple things like change tag autoplay to autoplay="true", moving javascript code down the page and nothing works. Also error console do not give me any errors.

Comment: Need autoplay audio? It is becoming impossible due to new browser policies. Google *"HTML5 audio autoplay"*.